# Error integrating MATLAB and Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, matlab

The program is simple, it just adds the two number. Here's my matlab function that I created and built in .NET Assembly

```
function out = addMe(a,b)
out = a+b;
end
```

I then use the NE builder toolbox to generate a .NET component: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/823/f77h.jpg

```
Imports Add

Public Class Form1
    Dim a As Integer = 5
    Dim b As Integer = 10
    Dim res
    Dim addme As New AddClass

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        res = addme.addMe(a, b)
        TextBox1.Text = res
    End Sub
End Class
```

But when I run the program, I'm getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load type 'Add.AddClass' from assembly 'Add, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  Source=Add
  StackTrace:
       at Add.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
       at Add.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Form1()
       at Add.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in c:\users\elvin gentiles\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Add\Add\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at Add.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
       HResult=-2146233054
       Message=Could not load type 'Add.AddClass' from assembly 'Add, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
       Source=Add
       TypeName=Add.AddClass
       StackTrace:
            at Add.Form1..ctor()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Do you deploy Matlab function into .NET? Have you tried adding required Matlab assemblies?

Comment: yeah. I deploy it into .NET using the deploytool. what assemblies are you talking? I just add the class and the .m file when I deploy my function. Here's the pic: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/823/f77h.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add required MatLab assembilies in your .NET application to run MatLab function.

Follow this link, I created that might give you some idea about adding Matlab assemblies:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-HmKmnsK88 (Part 2)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYJ7Q4liNYw (Part 1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already watched that video before I started doing the code in visual basic. I already imported and added the reference needed but it still not working.

Comment: What version of .NET you are using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @elvinguitar: I mean .NET version not VS. 3.5 or 4.0?

Comment: @elvinguitar: I think it won't work with .NET version higher than 2.0. Try to build and run with 2.0.

Comment: How should I do that? Sorry, but I'm not familiar with visual basic.

Comment: Do it again and create a new project in Visual Studio. File > New. Select Console Application and .NET version (2.0) somewhere above.

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/547/hdm5.jpg

Comment: By the way, I'm using MATLAB 2013a

Comment: It seems like it is missing some DLL file!

Comment: but I already added reference to all the .dlls that are needed